# Is there any way to programmatically set the zoom level of a Word document using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to change the default zoom level of word document

I have a word document which is created using python.
When I open that word document, It gets opened to the default zoom level which is 154%.
I want to change the default zoom level to 120%, so that whenever we open that file, it should get opened with zoom level of 120%.

Comment: may you upload your word file ... plz? ( https://uploadfiles.io/ )

Answer (score 2):

You might look into Document.settings object. It provide access to document-level settings for that document.
Something like this xml:

```
<w:zoom w:val="bestfit" w:percent="120"/>
```

See this: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/254

Comment: I want to add that in my python code, when I tried adding the above line it gave me an error saying " Namespace prefix w for val on zoom is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about that: [Automatically Opening a Document at a Specific Zoom Setting](https://word.tips.net/T001343_Automatically_Opening_a_Document_at_a_Specific_Zoom_Setting.html), but not in Python.

Comment: You could chain it as a set of actions in python with win32 module. Possible example here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-October/064831.html

Comment: Yes, I came across the same, while I was searching for the solution,but I want it using python.